# Will leaving a device on an NFC tag do any harm?

Tags: nfc

I want to leave my phone sat on an NFC tag all day long - will it do any harm to either the phone or the tag?

I'm worried about Android constantly trying to read the tag all day, and that this could cause unecessary battery use, the tag could get hot from constantly being read, etc etc.

Is there anything to back up these concerns, or is it fine to leave a device on an NFC tag for a long period of time? Will Android read the tag over and over again, or does it somehow know when it's placed on a new tag?

Note the device is a Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 7.0) and the tag is one of the cheap 'NFC stickers' you can get from amazon etc.

Edit: not a dupe of the linked question because that only asks about battery drain. This question is about adverse affects in general (e.g. over heating the tag).

Comment: Nothing to the tag, and nothing to the phone except for power drain.